# Does $R$ is Dedekind-finite imply $\mathbb{M}_n(R)$ is Dedekind-finite

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, matrix-theory, noncommutative-rings

Following Lam's notation, a ring (with identity) $R$ is called Dedekind-finite if $ab=1\iff ba=1$ in $R$.

There are a lot of result about left invertible implies right invertible. But the results all require some finiteness property on the ring or the matrix ring. I am asking a proof or a counterexample of that that $R$ is Dedekind-finite impies that the matrix ring $\mathbb{M}_n(R)$ is Dedekind-finite.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hopfian modules](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/234965/hopfian-modules)

Comment: @DavidHandelman Oops: I didn't think to search previous answers for the terminology "Hopfian". I see I've duplicated the answer you gave

Answer (score 7):

The answer is **no**, even for $n=2$.

One thng to note is that over the decades, different groups of authors have used different terminology. The property you call Dedekind-finite has been called directly finite, or von Neumann finite. Then given a unital ring $R$, people have asked when $M_n(R)$ is DF for all $n\geq 1$, and this property has been called *weakly finite* (I believe this terminology was introduced by P. M. Cohn) or *fully von Neumann finite*, or (in the context of ${\rm C}^*$-algebras) *stably finite*. I mention all this in case it helps to look things up in the literature.

It turns out that one can find a unital ring $R$ which has no non-trivial zero-divisors (so in particular no non-trivial idempotents, which in turn implies $R$ is Dedekind finite) yet has the property that $M_2(R)$ is not Dedekind finite. See

J. C. Shepherdson, *Inverses and zero divisors in matrix rings.*
Proc. London Math. Soc. (3) 1, (1951). 71–85. [MR0041831](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0041831)

which was pointed out to me by Mr A. Fisher.

I can't resist pointing out another example. Much later, it was shown that there is a unital, finite ${\rm C}^*$-algebra $A$ (which can be realised as an extension of $C({\mathbb T}^3)$ by the compacts) such that $M_k(A)$ is not DF for some $k\geq 2$; however, at a quick glance I don't see how to obtain an actual value of $k$ from the proof. The paper is:

N. P. Clarke, *A finite but not stably finite ${\rm C}^*$-algebra.*
[Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 96 (1986), 85–88](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1986-096-01/S0002-9939-1986-0813816-7/) | [MR0813816](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=813816)

Answer (score 5):

The question is answered in the negative in Exercise 1.18 of Lam's *Exercises in Modules and Rings* (2007 ed.): Start with the free $K$-algebra $K \langle X \rangle$ over a field $K$ generated by the $8$-element set $X = \{s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z\}$ and let $R$ be the quotient of $K \langle X \rangle$ by the two-sided ideal generated by the relations dictated by the equation $AB = I$ in the matrix ring $\mathcal M_2(K \langle X \rangle)$, where $I$ is the identity of $\mathcal M_2(K \langle X \rangle)$ and we put $A := \left[\begin{array}{cc} s & u \\ t & v \end{array}\right]$ and $B := \left[\begin{array}{cc} x & y \\ z & w \end{array}\right]$. It turns out that $R$ is a (non-commutative) domain and hence Dedekind-finite; but the matrix ring $\mathcal M_2(R)$ is not Dedekind-finite (essentially by design).

Lam explains in the comment after his solution that the construction first appeared in [J.C. Shepherdson, *Inverses and zero-divisors in matrix rings*, Proc. London Math, Soc. 1 (1951), 71-85]: This is the same paper mentioned by Yemon Choi in [their answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/279603/16537).